# How can I get a return and save it after click event - Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, dom-events

I can save the return by declaring  `const result = generateNumber();` but I would like to get it after implementing the click event. Is there any way for it?

```js
playBtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  generateNumber();
});


const threeRandNumber = [];
function generateNumber() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const randomNumber = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 10);

    if (threeRandNumber.indexOf(randomNumber) === -1) {
      threeRandNumber.push(randomNumber);
    }

    else {
      i--;
    }
  }
  return threeRandNumber;
}

const result = generateNumber();
```

Comment: `playBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){globalThis.result=generateNumber();});alert(window.result);`

Comment: `This is called "variable scoping". You can Google it for more details, but declaring a variable using const in a code block only defines it in that respective code block. You can use globalThis.varname = value; to make it accessible as window.varname.`

Comment: Try you define your playBtn button then write your last line inside the event listen er but define the varible at first line

Comment: You can't get the result after clicking, because the assignment doesn't wait for you to click.

Comment: Put whatever code that you want to receive the result inside your click handler as well.

Comment: You can use async but I really dont understand exactley what you want to do...